# Deserialization difference in Newtonsoft.Json.6.0.8 vs Newtonsoft.Json.12.0.3

Tags: json, serialization, json.net, deserialization

It seems there exists a difference in the way of deserialization process of Newtonsoft.Json.6.0.8 vs Newtonsoft.Json.12.0.3.

The following is model in our C# project :

```
 public class WebServiceConfigModel 
    {
        public string RestoreFile { get; set; }
        public string RestoreFileDescription { get; set; }
       
    }
```

The action method defined in the controller is as follows:

```
[HttpPost]
    public void Restore(WebServiceConfigModel request)
    {
    }
```

The input JSON text which was provided to the method is as follows:

```
{
  "RestoreFile": "SampleFile",
  "RestoreFileDescription": {
    "ID": "DatasetDescription",
    "Label": "Description"
   
  }
 
}
```

This was deserialized successfully (the request object contains values), even if there exists a deserialization error and we were able to read the RestoreFile property value in the C# while using the Newtonsoft.Json.6.0.8.

After upgrading the version Newtonsoft.Json to 12.0.3, the request object in C# seems to be null and the deserialization error still exists. It works properly if we change the "RestoreFileDescription" property to a string value.

Is there any way to get the deserialized object even if some of the property has a contract mismatch?

Comment: Is that the only update? Or are there other package updates?

Comment: Reisclef, It was updated to include the Google Oauth.  The other change was to include the Google Oauth libraries. And it seems to work if we downgrade the Newtonsoft version to 6.0.8.

Comment: Did my answer help at all?

Answer (score 0):

These [docs](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializationErrorHandling.htm) may be helpful.

It appears that as of 12.0.1, you can handle Json Deserialization errors in two ways:

1. JsonSerializerSettings.Error event
2. The [OnError] attribute

In the first instance, the JsonSerializerSettings have been set so as to handle a non-date string, and this is handled as per their docs:

> The event handler has logged these messages and Json.NET has continued on deserializing the JSON because the errors were marked as handled.

```
List<DateTime> c = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<DateTime>>(@"[
  '2009-09-09T00:00:00Z',
  'I am not a date and will error!',
  [
    1
  ],
  '1977-02-20T00:00:00Z',
  null,
  '2000-12-01T00:00:00Z'
]",
new JsonSerializerSettings
{
    Error = delegate(object sender, ErrorEventArgs args)
    {
        errors.Add(args.ErrorContext.Error.Message);
        args.ErrorContext.Handled = true;
    },
    Converters = { new IsoDateTimeConverter() }
});
```

The second way is to create a method, and decorate it with the [OnError] attribute as follows:

```
[OnError]
internal void OnError(StreamingContext context, ErrorContext errorContext)
{
    errorContext.Handled = true;
}


PersonError person = new PersonError
{
    Name = "George Michael Bluth",
    Age = 16,
    Roles = null,
    Title = "Mister Manager"
};
```

So when Roles is required, this provides the following result:

```
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(person, Formatting.Indented);

Console.WriteLine(json);

//{
//  "Name": "George Michael Bluth",
//  "Age": 16,
//  "Title": "Mister Manager"
//}
```